# Bash scripting to remove specific portion

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to write a script that will convert a fractional coordinate system into a Cartesian coordinate system.

Here, In the input file i have some unnecessary section i want to remove them. To remove upper unnecessary section i am just using `sed -i '1,7 s/.*//g' geometry.xyz` (first 7 lines are always not needed).
But my problem is the section i require may change in size. This looks something like:

```
%BLOCK LATTICE_CART
      10.000000000000000       0.000000000000000       0.000000000000000
       0.000000000000000      10.000000000000000       0.000000000000000
       0.000000000000000       0.000000000000000      10.000000000000000
%ENDBLOCK LATTICE_CART

%BLOCK POSITIONS_FRAC
  H   0.3242730364399766  -0.5778932059463918   0.4725289033063597
  H   0.3242730880505244  -0.4462573476378897   0.3408930320952251
  H   0.5269396206127043  -0.6403171603506288   0.3779836353112689
  H   0.4391824086567526  -0.6285598118052995   0.5417408894621464
  H   0.6929877354648144  -0.5297761432888469   0.4524840992286400
  H   0.6466039123419516  -0.6708589950924689   0.5647345854707825
  H   0.6049230092979219  -0.4959539583844693   0.6129729324712603
  H   0.4279396231283572  -0.3487419832103440   0.5700442724565965
  C   0.3622730487068306  -0.4740752814020994   0.4447109742648412
  C   0.4762730467994820  -0.4740752814020994   0.4447109742648412
  C   0.5142730074557883  -0.5778932235717150   0.4725289080290508
  C   0.6146969322498489  -0.5686205772550322   0.5256801349609578
  O   0.5142730074557883  -0.3980752729966930   0.5207109826702476
%ENDBLOCK POSITIONS_FRAC

%BLOCK KPOINTS_LIST
   0.0000000000000000   0.0000000000000000   0.0000000000000000       1.000000000000000
%ENDBLOCK KPOINTS_LIST

%BLOCK CELL_CONSTRAINTS
       1       2       3
       4       5       6
%ENDBLOCK CELL_CONSTRAINTS

FIX_COM : false
%BLOCK IONIC_CONSTRAINTS
%ENDBLOCK IONIC_CONSTRAINTS
```

Now i may have more Hydrogen or Oxygen or Carbon in my system. So, I want the script to find % and delete everything after that. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: It is certainly possible, but SO is not a write-my-code-for-free bargain. If you have any specific difficulty with code you are writing, edit your question including it and people here will be glad to help. Otherwise, try and show a sign of effort. Thanks.

Comment: You started off describing what you wanted then you started talking about extra oxygen without saying how that might look in your data! And then you want everything after a percent sign removed when your data is full of percent signs! Please show your expected output so we can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/%ENDBLOCK POSITIONS_FRAC/{ exit }; p; /%BLOCK POSITIONS_FRAC/{p = 1};' geometry.xyz
```

Would give

```
  H   0.3242730364399766  -0.5778932059463918   0.4725289033063597
  H   0.3242730880505244  -0.4462573476378897   0.3408930320952251
  H   0.5269396206127043  -0.6403171603506288   0.3779836353112689
  H   0.4391824086567526  -0.6285598118052995   0.5417408894621464
  H   0.6929877354648144  -0.5297761432888469   0.4524840992286400
  H   0.6466039123419516  -0.6708589950924689   0.5647345854707825
  H   0.6049230092979219  -0.4959539583844693   0.6129729324712603
  H   0.4279396231283572  -0.3487419832103440   0.5700442724565965
  C   0.3622730487068306  -0.4740752814020994   0.4447109742648412
  C   0.4762730467994820  -0.4740752814020994   0.4447109742648412
  C   0.5142730074557883  -0.5778932235717150   0.4725289080290508
  C   0.6146969322498489  -0.5686205772550322   0.5256801349609578
  O   0.5142730074557883  -0.3980752729966930   0.5207109826702476
```